# List column numbers if columns contain string

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that searches for the string "dog" in sheet1 of a workbook, the string can appear many times in the sheet, and it gives me a vector of the column numbers if the string was found in those columns, (dog can only appear once in each column). I have a button on the sheet which I assign this macro:

```
Option Explicit


Sub mymacro2()
Dim dog() As Integer
Dim coldog As Range
Set coldog = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Find("dog", , xlValues, xlWhole)
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
ReDim dog(0)
dog(i) = coldog.Column
Do
    i = i + 1
    ReDim Preserve dog(i)
    Set coldog = Sheets(1).UsedRange.FindNext(coldog)
    dog(i) = coldog.Column
Loop While dog(i) <> dog(0)

ReDim Preserve dog(i - 1)



Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(Application.Transpose(dog))) = dog
'above line is displaying the vector on the sheet for testing purposes
Set coldog = Nothing

ReDim dog(0)


End Sub
```

The macro gives me the vector I want, i.e. it tells me in which columns I can find the string "dog".

Now, I want to modify the code or create a whole new code that does the same thing for each string in a list of strings found in column 1 on sheet2. All the vectors with the column numbers has to have the same name as the string it has column information about. Like I do manually in the code above.

The point is I have a list of about 130 animals which I need to do the same thing for. What is the best way of doing that in Excel VBA?

Comment: it seems like you want us to write the code for you

Comment: @mehow I hope that this is not the case and that he is just looking for some overall ideas to confirm that his approach is right, how to evolve it, etc.

Comment: There must be some simple way to do this for many strings if a noob like me can do it for one string, right?

Comment: As you can see in my answer, there is a pretty simple way to do what you want (store all the elements in an array and iterate through it), your code is actually over-complicating things. Mehow is not saying that it is difficult; just that you cannot ask us to write a code for you (no matter how simple it is): you are the one who has to do it. I wrote a code to explain the point quickly and clearly, I hope that will be enough for you (and this is what you were looking for: explanations; not working codes).

Comment: I think there should be some nice way to feed excel with some strings in order to give me the position of all instances of the strings if they exist on a worksheet.

Comment: A nice way? You think that one line of code (Set tempRange = targetRange.Find(animals(i), , xlValues, xlWhole)) is not nice enough? But if you want to account for different inputs, you have to feed them (this is what the initial array and the loop are for). What do you expect? To input the word "animals" and VBA to understand that you want a specific list of 130 animals?! I am not sure if I am starting to regret having answered here: you want to understand how to improve your knowledge (because you have some) or are you looking for a code which you will execute blindly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to store all the animals in another `Array` and call the given actions for each of them. Also your code has quite a few redundant parts. The sample code below should give you a good grasp to understand how to face this problem (as said via comment by Mehow, we are not here to write codes for you).

```
Dim totAnimals As Integer, i As Integer
totAnimals = 3
ReDim animals(totAnimals - 1) As String
animals(0) = "dog"
animals(1) = "cat"
animals(2) = "mouse"
'etc.

maxMatches = 100 'Maximum number of matches per animal. better don't make this value too big
ReDim matchCount(totAnimals - 1) 'This counter goes from 1 to maxMatches
ReDim matchCols(totAnimals - 1, maxMatches) As Integer

Dim targetRange As Range, tempRange As Range, tempRange2 As Range
Set targetRange = Sheets("sheet2").Columns(1)

For i = 0 To totAnimals - 1
    Set tempRange = targetRange.Find(animals(i), , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If (Not tempRange Is Nothing) Then
        If (matchCount(i) + 1 <= maxMatches) Then
            matchCount(i) = matchCount(i) + 1

            matchCols(i, matchCount(i)) = tempRange.Column
            Dim startAddress As String: startAddress = tempRange.Address
            Set tempRange2 = tempRange
            Do
                Set tempRange2 = targetRange.FindNext(tempRange2)
                If (Not tempRange2 Is Nothing) Then
                    If (tempRange2.Address = startAddress) Then Exit Do
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
                If (matchCount(i) + 1 > maxMatches) Then Exit Do
                matchCount(i) = matchCount(i) + 1
                matchCols(i, matchCount(i)) = tempRange2.Column
            Loop While (Not tempRange2 Is Nothing)
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: @steinbitur sorry but I don't get what you mean. That I wrote a code as an answer to a question? I do that pretty often (like here), it is easier for me writing the code than long explanations. But if you take a look at this answer (or any other one), you would see that the OP wasn't asking for a code from scratch (like you) but why his code wasn't working. As said, it is faster to write code than explaining (and, usually, create my own code better than editing the OP's one). I told you: this has nothing to do with difficult/easy, but with what you request.

Comment: @steinbitur PS: the code in this answer is also a nice working one. Actually, it delivers exactly what you want.

Comment: @steinbitur PPS: the attitude of the OP is really important (a person trying to do something but failing and needing some help VS. someone not even trying), also whatever I feel like doing the given day :) (as far as I guess that I don't need to give you any kind of justification of what I do... what I (or Mehow) said was a mere indication of what people usually think here but there is no rule: I (or anyone) can do whatever I want).

Comment: Your code only finds the first instance of each I guess. There could be three of dog, 1 of cat and 50 of mouse.

Comment: @steinbitur As said from the start, the intention was providing the main framework (on which you should work further). Even in this preliminary version it works fine. If you want to extend its functionalities, you should do it by your own (the FindNext in your original code does the trick pretty well). In any case, if you want to store various values per animal you have to rely on a 2D array; I will update my code to reflect this (how to deal with a 2D array), but this is it.

Comment: Thanks buddy, your too good a programmer, I´ll learn a lot from that I know :D

Comment: @steinbitur No problem (if it is to learn, no problem at all). Please, take a look at the last update of my code where I am bringing "maxMatches" into account.